# Installing Ros2 on the Jetson Xavier Nano

Tags: computer-vision, rosinstall

My team and I are trying to install Ros2 on the Jetson Xavier Nano so or robot can have computer vision, but the Jetson runs an old version of Ros. How can newer versions of ROS be used on the Jetson platform?

Answer (score 2):

The [NVidia Documentation provides some resources on this](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/accelerating-ai-modules-for-ros-and-ros-2-on-jetson/). One easy method that they recommend is to make use of the docker images that they provide, for example:

```
docker pull nvidiajetson/l4t-ros2-foxy-pytorch:r32.5
```

At time of writing, the [NVidia Jetson custom Linux distribution](https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/jetpack-sdk-512) is based on Ubuntu 20.04, so if you continue to use this distribution, you'll be locked to the versions of ROS that are compatible with Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

I never did it on the jetson xavier nano, but when I did it on the jetson nano platform I had to boot from a USB and/or do a distro upgrade, found in either [this tutorial](https://github.com/JetsonHacksNano/rootOnUSB) or from the same creator. It is a sketchy process and you risk ruining the nano (which I did do once). But you are able to get ubuntu 20.04 and thus ros2 foxy on it. Other than that docker images are your best bet. This was >1 year ago so there might be a distro upgrade out there for ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with a Jetson Nano but I was recently able to get ROS2 Foxy installed on Xavier NX running Jetpack 5. The full desktop version seemed to have a lot of dependency issues but `sudo apt install ros-foxy-ros-base python3-argcomplete` worked for me.

The problem I foresee in your case is that Nano only has Jetpack 4.6 as its last supported official OS release based on Ubuntu 18.04 so foxy will not work out of the box. You might have to try an older version like [ROS2 Eloquent](https://docs.ros.org/en/eloquent/index.html), or give building from source a go.

While building from source, try using a reliable source like this [JetsonHacks bash script](https://github.com/jetsonhacks/installROS2/blob/master/installROS2.sh) which in turn refers to [Nvidia's ROS install scripts](https://github.com/dusty-nv/jetson-containers/tree/master/packages/ros) used to build even their containers for a list of commands and it might save some dependency chasing.

Hope this helps!

Comment: [This recent Discourse post](https://discourse.ros.org/t/setting-up-stereolabs-zed-x-for-ros-2/33534) might be relevant, as it mentions a video tutorial on "Install ROS 2 Humble on Nvidia Jetson Orin AGX (which runs annoyingly 20.04 requiring some special steps)".